# Make auto become a reference if reference is returned by function

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, type-inference, auto

I need the following code to work:

```
class Parent{
public:
     virtual void fun(){throw 0};

};

class Child:public Parent{
public:
     virtual void fun(){/*Success*/};

};
Parent& getChild(){
     return *(new Child());
}

void main(){
    auto child=getChild();
    child.fun();    
}
```

But for some reason `auto` creates a `Parent` instead of `Parent &` which would correctly use the derived method. Is there a way to force `auto` to create a reference instead of using a simple Instance?

Comment: Use `autp&` maybe? Also note that you return a pointer in that function not a reference.

Comment: `auto&` or `decltype(auto)`. "But for some reason auto creates a instead of which would correctly use the derived method" because `auto` uses template type deduction.

Comment: @russian_symbols fixed

Comment: @george that helps, thanks

Comment: No. `auto` by itself will always be a non-reference type. It's possible to do this with some creating templating and specialization, though. However the syntax will be pretty verbose, and not as straightforward as a direct declaration. The basic approach would be to use `decltype()`, feed the result to a template parameter, specialization for a reference, and use that to derive the type of the object that stores the return type from the function.

Comment: `getChild` is a very poor design as the caller is unaware they need to free it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ standard explains that auto is deducted from the initilizer value:

> Declarations `[dcl.spec.auto]/1:` The `auto` and `decltype(auto)`
>   type-specifiers are used to designate a placeholder type that will be
>   replaced later by **deduction from an initializer.**
>
> Initializers `[dcl.init]/1:`   A declarator can specify an **initial
>   value** for the identifier being declared.

So when you write the following declarators:

```
int t = f(10); 
auto x = y; 
auto child = getChild();
```

the right side is **evaluated as an expression** that yields a value. And this value is used to initialize the variable declared on the left side.

A value is not a reference.  It's not like pointers and adresses.  In an expression evaluation, whenever a reference is used, it's the referred value that is taken into consideration.  You can see this with the following simple snippet:

```
int x=15;
int&y = x; 
cout << x <<", " << y <<", " << &x<<endl;
cout << typeid(x).name() <<", " << typeid(y).name() <<", " << typeid(&x).name() <<endl;
```

In your case, the expression value is therefore a `Parent` and not `Parent &`.  This is why your `auto` will be deduced to have the `Parent` type.

The C++ standard does however not consider all the values in the same manner.  In `[basic.lval]` it makes an important distinction between different kind of values, which can be *lvalues*, *xvalues* and *prvalues*.  In your case `getChild()` evaluates to an lvalue that is the object to which you referred and not some temporary copy of it.

When you have such an lvalue, you can create a reference to it:

> `[dcl.ref]`/2: A reference type that is declared using `&` is called an
>   lvalue reference, (...)

But you need to do this explicitly by saying that your auto should be a reference:

```
auto &child = getChild();
```

***Edit:*** More infos on the way auto works: [Herb Sutter's GotW blog](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/07/gotw-92-solution-auto-variables-part-1/)